# Output .mov using AVAssetWriter with blank audio track

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I am using AVAssetWriter, AVAssetWriterInput, and AVAssetWrinterInputPixelBufferAdaptor to take an X number of UIImages and export them to a movie.  The problem I am running into is that the video exports with no audio track.  How can you add a muted audio track to AVAssetWriter?

Comment: Why do you want to add a muted audio track? you can export the video without audio track.

Comment: @Legna I am sending the exported clips to an audio and video AVMutableCompositionTrack.  I'm trying to avoid having empty gaps in the audio track.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Having similar issue where the gaps aren't their when playing on android devices, but are (as they should be) with IOS.  So I'm figuring putting a muted track to my first scene will stop this mis-sync.

Comment: @berr08 I didn't figure out the source of the problem but there is a work around.  I created silent CMSampleBufferRef's to the audio track.  See this question for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441648/create-a-silent-audio-cmsamplebufferref